# Experimenting With Algebraic Abstraction

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I am a novice attempting to understand the "abstract" components of mathematics.

Consequently, I have devised mathematical statements that I would like to be verified by knowledgeable users using the website.

$C = 0,1,2,3,4,5,...$

$a = C$<sub>$n$</sub>

$b = C$<sub>$n+1$</sub>

This is my criteria for the addition binary operation:

$(a + b) \implies (a > b \implies (a - b)) \vee (b > a \implies (b - a))$

I am attempting to eliminate commutativity by utilizing mathematical logic to show that when manipulating quantities via addition, the operand positions are such that $(a + b) ≠ (b + a)$

The numerical quantities within sequence "C" are whole/counting numbers.

Please give me advice on my mathematical interpretation. I would like to revise this expression accordingly.

I apologize for using the equivalency relations incorrectly. I intended to use "a > b" and "b < a" as "alternate" predicates to simulate "if-else" statements.

Comment: What does $C[n]$ mean?

Comment: I am referring to the nth element of the set.

Comment: What do you mean by "criteria for the addition binary operation"? Are you trying to define $a + b$ as a predicate on $C$? Why are you "attempting to eliminate commutativity", and what do you mean by "the elemental order"?

Comment: How can $a= a -b$. This is only true if $b=0$, contradicting the definition of $b$ as $n+1 \geq 1$. Similarly it can't be that $b=b-a$, so the antecedent of the conditional is always false. What's confusing is that $a+b$ is not a predicate, and so your implication seems to be ill-formulated in the first place